# OWL rdfs:langString and restricting its allowed languages

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

Is it possible in OWL to restrict a Property with a range like

```
demo:property rdfs:range rdf:langString
```

so that we only allow "en" and "de" as languages?

So

```
demo:object demo:property "hello"@en
```

would be allowed, but

```
demo:object demo:property "bonjour"@fr
```

would not.

Comment: `rdf:langString` was created and standardised with RDF 1.1 in 2014, while the latest version of OWL, OWL 2, was standardised in 2009, then updated in 2012. So OWL does not use `rdf:langString` at all. Instead, it defines the special datatype `rdf:PlainLiteral` which works as [Stanislav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425926/1260887) explains in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [4.3 Strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Strings):

> The OWL 2 datatype map provides the *rdf:PlainLiteral* datatype for the representation of strings in a particular language. The definitions of the value space, the lexical space, the facet space, and the necessary mappings are given in [[*RDF:PLAINLITERAL*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-rdf-plain-literal-20121211/)]. The normative constraining facets for *rdf:PlainLiteral* are *xsd:length*, *xsd:minLength*, *xsd:maxLength*, *xsd:pattern*, and ***rdf:langRange***; furthermore, only *basic language ranges* [[*BCP 47*](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt)] are supported in the *rdf:langRange* constraining facet.

Thus, in the Manchester syntax:

```
DataProperty: demo:property
    Range: 
        (rdf:PlainLiteral[langRange "de"] or rdf:PlainLiteral[langRange "en"]
```

In Turtle:

```
demo:property a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:range [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
        owl:unionOf ( [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                        owl:onDatatype rdf:PlainLiteral ;
                        owl:withRestrictions ( [ rdf:langRange "de" ] )
                      ]
                      [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                        owl:onDatatype rdf:PlainLiteral ;
                        owl:withRestrictions ( [ rdf:langRange "en" ] )
                      ]
                    )
                ] .
```

Now create 3 individuals (in Turtle):

```
demo:object_en a owl:NamedIndividual ;
               demo:property "demo"@en .

demo:object_de a owl:NamedIndividual ;
               demo:property "demo"@de .

demo:object_fr a owl:NamedIndividual ;
               demo:property "demo"@fr .
```

Then start a reasoner and look into inconsistency explanation.